# Не работает автовыдача роли | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Пытался найти что не так, но толком ничего на тему ошибок с автовыдачей ролей я не нашел. Никакой ошибки в консоль не выдает, просто не реагирует на вход пользователя на сервер.

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    new = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=767446695294140426)
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.channel, id=767470344189247590)
    await member.add_roles(new)
    await channel.send(f"{member.mention} joined to channel!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На [в категории **Bot** приложения](https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/) нужно поставить следующие галочки, и всё должно будет заработать:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    new = member.guild.get_role(767446695294140426)
    channel = member.guild.get_channel(767470344189247590)
    await member.add_roles(new)
    await channel.send(f"{member.mention} joined to channel!")
```

Comment: Не помогло, тот же результат

Comment: Хм, должно работать так как у меня такой самый код

Comment: Вот и я не понимаю, почему у меня не работает